# Angular+MVC: dynamic application loading or two separate applications?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, web

Need help with AngularJs project structure. I have an ASP.NET MVC + Web API application (MVC part here is just landing page + authentication pages. After this it redirects on Index.cshtml with the application itself). The problem is that depending on a user I have to show two "kind of different" applications (there are small core-main part and lots of not shared widgets).

Right now it's one browserified application. However, I've encountered a problem that I need the same routing.

Solutions which I see: implement 2 applications and redirect to different Index.chtml page after login.
Or somehow bootstrap core module and dynamically load 1st or 2nd application with its routing. But not sure that it's possible with AngularJs.

Edit:
to be more specific. I want to load one Angular application if you go to www.app/todo if person is Admin and load 2nd Angular application on same url www.app/todo if person is Not Admin. Of course there are lots of other modules, routes and bla-bla-bla.

Any thought, help?

Comment: Looks like I could use https://github.com/jas/gulp-preprocess to exclude not necessary parts in one module. However, I still have to have 2 separate  Index.cshtml pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using gulp, [this](https://github.com/jas/gulp-preprocess) might be what you are looking for.

It preprocesses your files before passing them to gulp-browserify and may generate different versions based on some conditions.

So you will need to update some of you js files (most likely angular routes and module connections) to get two different angular apps after preprocessing.

Finally, you will get n js files for each of your conditions (admin, regular user, etc.) and will choose what js file to include on the page.